# jquery: make get() before form submitting

Tags: jquery, get

here is my code. Question is how can i make async get() query before form submit? One another callback? How should it looks like?

```
$('#auth').submit(function(e) {
    var self=this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        //some code
    });
    self.submit();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit the form only when the request has finished

```
$('#auth').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = this;

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        //some code
        self.submit();
    });
});
```

It generally makes little sense to do an ajax request, sending data to the server, right before you submit a form that also sends data to the server.